# Dielectric break down of stacked glass layers

Tags: touchscreen, touch-panel, dielectric-breakdown

We have a capacitive touch panel with 1 mm thick cover glass.

Currently it is failing at 15kV ESD.

I am assuming that dielectric breakdown of the glass occurred and the touch driver is exposed to higher ESD and failed.  To increase and finalize the thickness of glass, I am doing a test.

Questions:

If I add a another 1mm thick glass sheet above the panel and test, how does the ESD voltage get divided between the glass layers?

Will it be divided equally or 
if the first glass dielectric breaks, will its resistivity be reduced?

Can you please share links to any literature to understand better?

Comment: Why 15 kV? What standard are you testing to?

Comment: Borosilicate glass would survive it. Normal glass probably wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes" and "yes".

However, by adding an extra layer of glass you are effectively adding another resistor in series and halving the voltage across each. But if one breaks down, so will the other.